# What is the official website to apply for a Moroccan e-visa?

Tags: online-resources, morocco, e-visas

I am a Pakistani living in Germany with a Blue card. I have read that I can quality for an e-visa for tourism.

I want to apply for an e-visa but haven't found the official site yet. The sites that I find show a higher fee than mentioned in different articles. Plus, those sites don't look official.

I have already had to unnecessarily pay extra once while applying for Turkey's visa so want to be sure this time.

If anyone has experience with evisa, would be great if you could share the official way.

Answer (score 4):

The official Moroccan e-Visa website:

### https://www.acces-maroc.ma/

source: [Moroccan Ministry of Foreign Affairs](https://www.diplomatie.ma/index.php/en/going-abroad)